# Retrieve dynamic checkbox value and pass to submit value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i would like to pass values from dynamic checkbox into submit button value.. i have tried this fidle tutorial (http://jsfiddle.net/kcd6r/) that i got from here, unfortunately it's only for 1 group of check box, my problem is if i have more than 1 group of check box and pass the total value to different submit button.. check below html code

```
<div id="dermal">
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="price1" name="price1[]" value="245" rel="245" >$245</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="price2" name="price2[]" value="245" rel="245" >$245</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="price3" name="price3[]" value="245" rel="245" >$245</p>
    <p><input type="submit" id="sum_price1" value="submit" name="submit1" /></p>
</div> 
<div id="wrinkle">
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="price4" name="price4[]" value="279" rel="279" >$279</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="price5" name="price5[]" value="279" rel="279" >$279</p>
    <p><input type="submit" id="sum_price2" value="submit" name="submit2" /></p>
</div>
```

anybody can help me?

1. how to retrieve value from group of check box
2. and pass it into each submit value above

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this,

```
$("#dermal input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
    });
```

this will select only the checkboxes inside deramal div

```
$("#wrinkle input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
    });
```

this will select only the check boxes in wrinkle div

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function recalculate() {
    var sum = 0;

    $("#dermal input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
    });

   $("#wrinkle input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
    });

    $("#output").html(sum);
}

$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    recalculate();
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/6FTbx/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function recalculate() {
        var sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

        $("#dermal input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            sum1 += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
        });
        $("#wrinkle input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            sum2 += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
        });

        $("#output1").html(sum1);
        $("#output2").html(sum2);
    }

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        recalculate();
    });
});
```